# Getting http error 400 urllib2 when trying to download a file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Here is the thing, i'm doing a script that download files from different sites. The thing is that i can't figure out why it throws me this error while if i put the same url on my browsers it let me download the files. Also there are other urls that works fine. So... here is the code:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import urllib2

f = urllib2.Request(url)
f.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0')
request = urllib2.urlopen(f)
data = request.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
p_name = soup.find('h2', id="searchResults").contents[0]
if not os.path.exists(p_name):
  os.makedirs(p_name)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href="#register"):
    f = a["data-durl"]
#Following two lines just prepares file name
    n = len(f.split("/"))
    n_file = f.split("/")[n-1]
    path_file = p_name+"\\"+n_file
    if os.path.isfile(path_file):
        print "Firmware already downloaded. skipping it"
    else:
        print "Downloading "+ path_file
        link = urllib2.urlopen(f)
        datos = link.read()
#print "[+] Downloading firmware %s" % n_file
#n_archivo = "Archivo"+str(b)+".zip"
        with open(path_file, "wb") as code:
           code.write(datos)
    time.sleep(2)
```

This url just wont work with this script :[Non working url](http://downloadcenter.netgear.com/en/product/ME101#searchResults)
But this one works fine [working url](http://downloadcenter.netgear.com/en/product/WNAP210)

Hope you can help me.

EDIT: I added the libraries that i use for this.
And the stack trace
I found the error!! Problem was spaces on the name of the file it tries to download. With f.replace(" ","%20") should work fine :)

Comment: Both URLs work fine for me. Where did you get the error? Please post full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert spaces in your filename to the URL encoding for a space: `%20`. To do this, you can add a line between these two lines using `str.replace()`:

```
print "Downloading "+ path_file
f = f.replace(' ', '%20')
link = urllib2.urlopen(f)
```

This will download from the url:

```
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/ME101/ME101%20Software%20Utility%20Version%202.0.zip
```

instead of from

```
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/ME101/ME101 Software Utility Version 2.0.zip
```

which is invalid because it contains spaces.

This URL still works in your browser because when you enter a URL with spaces, your browser will automatically convert them to `%20`.

Comment: No problem! Happy hunting!